# Obter valor do campo Mongo como Variavel?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Senhores, estou usando esse codigo no Meteor:

```
var teste = Orders.findOne({name : 'Day'}).day;
```

Para Obter o valor day nesse registro:

```
{_id: "HzoGFKRmYzmH8Yx6A", name: "Day", day: "Jan 27th 18"}
```

Ele da um erro, mas resgata o valor que eu quero, existe alguma forma de resgatar esse valor sem esse erro?

Comment: Onde estás a executar este (`var teste = Orders.findOne({name : 'Day'}).day;`) comando, no server-side ou client-side?

Answer (score 1):

O `findOne` é uma instrução assíncrona, portanto a forma correta de acessar o resultado da consulta é no *callback*, dessa forma:

```
Orders.findOne({name : 'Day'}, function(err, day){
    if (!err){
        let teste = day; // aqui a variavel teste recebe o retorno da consulta
    }
});
```

Comment: mano, obrigado pela resposta, mas continua dando erro, foi esse erro aqui:                                                                                             
            Exception in template helper: Error: Match error: Failed Match.OneOf, Match.Maybe or Match.Optional validation
    at exports.check (http://localhost:3000/packages/check.js?hash=eab389b8683d2f0b47a9d511894c2082fc6155a9:65:15)
    at Mongo.Collection._getFindOptions (http://localhost:3000/packages/mongo.js?hash=337de4ed4979262aa9b84177742e90e72b1e1e1c:344:7)

Comment: está usando meteor? esse parece ser um outro problema..

Comment: eh, estou usando Meteor, essa instrucao eh dentro de uma helper....sua resposta parece certa mesmo e deveria funcionar....estranho ne....

Comment: De uma olhada [nesse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26104937/meteor-match-error-failed-match-oneof-or-match-optional-validation-websocket) post

Comment: dei uma olhada la, mas nao consigo achar o problema....esta tudo subscrito e publicado corretamente, pois uso outras instrucoes semelhantes em outros arquivos, ta ligado...

Comment: essa nao da erro : Orders.find({name : 'Day'},{limit : 1 }, function(err, day)                                                          mas nao executa a funcao que coloco.....tava vendo que eh referente algo ao findOne

Comment: Perdao, acredito que dei uma resposta para partindo do principio que estava usando mongoose. tente `var teste = Orders.find({name : 'Day'},{limit : 1 })` somente. Entao na linha de baixo exibir o valor de teste.

Comment: essa funciona sem erro, mas me devolve o cursor (o registro todo), eu quero so o campo day, que esta inserido nesse registro.... agradeco demais sua disponiblidade meu irmao

Comment: como mostrado nesse registro: {_id: "HzoGFKRmYzmH8Yx6A", name: "Day", day: "Jan 27th 18"}

Comment: `var teste = Orders.find({name : 'Day'},{limit : 1, fields: {'day':1} })` tente assim Neto

Comment: mano, da certo sim, mas ele retorna o cursor, o registro Json. Eu queria que ele me retornasse so o valor do field.....o engracado eh que no console no navegador da certo, mas no meteor nao funciona.....mesmo que eu negue o aparecimento dos outros campos, ele continua retornando como Json

Comment: olha essa aqui, era pra funcionar, mas da undefined:                                                                                                       var teste = Orders.find({name : 'Day'}, {limit : 1}).fetch();
var teste2 = teste.day;

console.log(teste2);

Comment: O que te impede de fazer [isso](https://jsfiddle.net/18urx8wL/)?

Comment: porque eu vou usar o valor adquirido como busca de outro find, ai ele nao vai aceitar dessa forma....

Comment: Pode testar isso tb: `var teste = Object.values(Orders.find({name : 'Day'},{limit : 1, fields: {'day':1} }))[0];`

Comment: tambem nao deu, retorna cursor....pense velho kkkkkkkk

Comment: Me mostra a forma que vai usar em outro find

Comment: Orders.find({orderDate: teste, userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();

Comment: Cara, ja tentou `Orders.find({orderDate: teste['day'], userId: Meteor.userId()}).fetch();`?

Comment: nada, isso ta mto estranho mano, era pra funcionar...mas o console continua dando undefined e nao dando certo.....esse resultado vem de um prompt que pergunto ao usuario o dia da ordem que ele quer ver....vc saberia uma outra forma de passar as informacoes do events para o helper, sem precisar inserir no db ??? porque estou fazendo isso, insiro no banco com o events, depois resgato com o helper

Answer (score 0):

Mano, essa funciounou:

Orders.find({name : 'Day'}).fetch().forEach(function(day){
            var day = day.day;
        console.log(day);

Answer (score 0):

Cara... pra mim funciona sem erro. Mas por via de sintax, coloque o nome do campo da sua coleção entre aspas simples e o valor a ser buscado em aspas duplas, assim:

```
let teste = Orders.findOne({'name': "Day"}).day;
console.log(teste);
```